# Plotting XYZ in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, xyz

I have UTM coordinates data XY and Z which shows the presence of mountain. For Z, I have just binary data.

```
1 = presence of mountains, and
0 = absence of mountains (presence of sediments in other words).
```

I am wondering that how can I plot it in ArcMap?

Comment: Try [Make XY Event Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm)

Comment: after you bring in like @BERA said, then you can plot the mountain flags by category as shown here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/drawing-a-layer-using-categories.htm

Comment: I don't think "sediments" are the opposite of "mountains."

Comment: CSK... then may be we can say soil. The data i am working with is about clay, silt, sand and coarse particles. Thank you very much for all the answers. I will try this method in morning and will let you guys know the results.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that this data is in a table. If that is the case, in the Table Of Contents, right click the table and choose 'Display XY Data'. This will open a window that will allow you to specify the fields for the X, Y, and Z data.

[image]

This will then display the records in the table on the map in the specified coordinate system. (ensure that you choose the correct fields for X and Y and that your coordinate system is correct, or else your features will end up far away from where they really are)

I would leave the Z field as "None" and make that field a *status* field that you could then use to color code the points as a mountain or not a mountain.